# How to map the Tab key to *select* auto-complete options in WebStorm instead of *inserting* them

Tags: pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

The default auto-complete behaviour in WebStorm is to insert the highlighted option when hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key - options are selected with arrow keys.

Can <kbd>Tab</kbd> be mapped to instead scroll the auto-complete options (and maybe <kbd>Shift + Tab</kbd> backwards), and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert (which can be done in VS Code)? Can't seem to find anything in the WS keymap settings.

Comment: 1) `Enter` is used to insert currently selected entry as is ("Choose Lookup Item" action) ... and `Tab` will *replace* the current element under caret with the entry from completion popup ("Choose Lookup Item Replace" action) -- they are 2 different actions.

Comment: 2) The next / prev navigation in a list -- they are done using the same keys as in other menus and popups of that kind -- the standard `Up` and `Down` actions. **There are no separate up/down for navigating in menus only.** See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-270167#focus=Comments-27-4916760.0-0

Comment: 3) Based on the above -- you can assign additional shortcuts for `Up` and `Down` actions ... but then they will conflict with other actions that have the same shortcut while in the Editor (e.g. indent a line, insert actual Tab etc)... which is highly undesirable for you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comments. I'm aware of (1) - probably should have been clearer on that... Shame up/down can't be mapped for auto-complete only. I've RSI in my little finger simply due to arrow keys, so I tend remap them to tab or eg. Ctrl+J/K wherever I can.

Comment: *"so I tend remap them to tab or eg. Ctrl+J/K wherever I can."* -- IdeaVim? (I remember seeing such shortcuts used there for such nav). BTW -- you can map `J/K` to those actions (they **should** work in menus; at very least it was implemented for quite a few places -- see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218745 and linked tickets)